# Team Foundation Server CLI login

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to connect to my company's TFS server from a Linux CLI. I'm using TEE version TEE-CLC-11.0.0. The problem is that the CLI is not authenticating to the domain. I have verified connectivity from another Windows machine using MS Team explorer for VS2012 where I can see the collections and projects on the server using these same credentials.

When I try to connect using the following formats, I do not even get an error message, TF just prints out the whole help menu. I've tried all the login formats listed in the help menu as well as those on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh190725.aspx#LoginOption

Formats I've tried:

```
./tf -login:user@domain -server:http://tfs-server:8080/tfs

./tf -login:domain\\user,pass -server:http://tfs-server:8080/tfs
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your TFS instance configured to use Kerberos? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg475929.aspx

Comment: It's printing the help because you haven't given it a command.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @jessehouwing: I'm not sure but I'd prefer to get the interactive method working if possible.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> It's printing the help because you haven't given it a command. What are you trying to do?
> ```

Yes, that seems to be the problem - I was not submitting any commands!
I was trying to verify authentication was working first.
Thanks Edward.